# using ajax to do a pre-registration check and then redirecting to a proper page

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

I have a registration form for my website that requires a user to fill in ~6 fields, with their email as their username on the system. When a user registers, I want to first check if they are not already a registered user in our system, and if they are, redirect them to the login page. If they are not registered, registration should proceed to the registration page.

I've been trying to do this with the following ajax code, but it doesn't  work - if the user is already registered, it still proceeds to the registration page:

```
function Chkreg()
{   
    var uemail = document.registration.email;  
var not_reg;

$.ajax({
    async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "chkreg.php",
        data : "email="+uemail.value,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var success = data['success'];
            if(success == false){
                var error = data['message'];
                alert(error);
                window.location.href="login.php";
                not_reg = false;
                return false;
            }
            if(success == true) {
                not_reg = true;
                return true; 
            }
        }
    });//end ajax
    return not_reg:;
}//end  function
```

The form itself is defined as follows:

```
`<form name='registration' method="POST" action="registration/register.php" onsubmit="return Chkreg();">`
```

so, a false return from the Chkreg function should not post to register.php, but Chkreg() seems to always return true.

Any ideas how to fix it, or an alternate way to do this?

Comment: is your chkreg.php file returning the correct values for the registered and non-registered cases ?

Comment: The data['success'] variable might be returning a string with 'false' in it, try some more rigorous checking for that response.

Comment: I found the problem - stupid typo! an extra ':" after return not_reg. thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're doing the ajax call with async:false, you don't need the return true or return false inside of it.  That could be where things are going wrong, since you are returning from the anonymous function in the ajax call, not Chkreg().  Just returning not_reg outside of the ajax call will work.

That said, I would declare not_reg = false when you initialize the var.  That way it's false until proven true.  Or vice-y-versa -- I can't tell because of the negation in the variable name.

Also, inside of your (success == false) if-block, you are executing

```
window.location.href = "login.php";
```

which immediately redirects the user to login.php.  You may want to alter the flow entirely and change the inline js for the form's onsubmit event

```
onsubmit="Chkreg(); return false;"
```

Then, inside Chkreg(), you could submit the form with javascript if they are not a registered user already.

Also, === and !== are preferred over == and != (especially when establishing if a variable is true or false, in case your values can be interpreted as truthy).

Lastly, Developer Tools are your friend (or Firebug).  What response is the server giving when chkreg.php is being requested?

Answer (score 0):

Check what the actual response is with firebug (or whatever your browsers dev kit)....I would be what you want is

```
if (success == "false") {
```